# Why LiveReload doesn't work with Firefox and how to fix it?

Tags: firefox, livereload

I have a problem with Livereload and in particular with Firefox. When I install the add-on in Firefox, the icon in the browser isn't shown?

P.S. Firefox version is 43.0.4, Livereload - 2.1.1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Click the "hamburger" at the far right of the main toolbar to open the menu and then click "customize" at the bottom.  The icon you're looking for is listed with the other "additional tools and features" and can be dragged to the toolbar.
I had to restart firefox after that to get it to actually enable livereload when I clicked on it.

Ps.  It also took me a while to find the right source for the livereload plugin that would actually load into firefox: ( addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/livereload/?src=search ) but you seem to have figured that part out.

Comment: I've got it! Thanks! :)